# How do I prevent data injection?

Tags: php

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE **UserId = " + txtUserId**

How do I prevent data injection?

The following code is appropriate?

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $GET['username'] );
mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE username = '".$username."'");
```

Comment: https://owasp.org/www-community/Injection_Theory

Answer (score -1):

PDO will protect you from injections http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
Use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
For example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

This is a secure code

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin Added an example.